# How to trigger listener to a server

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, ip, iot

I have a hardware device which is sending the data continuously to an configured IP and port

```
for example : 192.168.137.2:8080
```

Actually if it is AWS instance then using AWS console it is possible to see the data coming from the device directly without any web-service or application.

So i want to know whether Is there any way to see the data coming from device on dedicated server without any application?

**Is it possible to add a listener or something similar to that so that we can read the data in dedicated server?**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? If everything is local not on AWS you want to know is there a service through which you can read data being sent to your server (not on aws ) ?

Comment: edited the question..check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by TCP sockets.

I created a simple socket application which was expecting an IP and listening to a PORT and established the connection between the device and the server.